# Dockerfile COPY package.json ./ works on local correctly but fails on gitlab pipeline

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, gitlab, dockerfile

File Directory
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHJHf.png)

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

ENV PORT=5000

EXPOSE 5000

CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]
```

[running docker file locally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nKRP.png)

```
    Login Succeeded
$ docker build -t $CI_DOCKER_REPO:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA -f ./cronTest/Dockerfile .
Step 1/9 : FROM node:16
 ---> e90654c39524
Step 2/9 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4ffb8744c0c4
Step 3/9 : RUN ls
 ---> Running in 992c3cd680f3
Removing intermediate container 992c3cd680f3
 ---> 0124eea0f9e9
Step 4/9 : COPY package.json ./
COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat package.json: file does not exist
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Even though the same file is used can anyone check this if something is wrong with my dockerfile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The local build and the pipeline build are launching from different paths, but both are provided with the same `.` *relative* build context, which means they resolve to different paths.

To emulate the local build, supply the equivalent "build context" paramater

```
docker build -t $CI_DOCKER_REPO:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA \
  -f ./cronTest/Dockerfile \
  ./crontTest
```

Or move into the same directory

```
cd cronTest
docker build -t $CI_DOCKER_REPO:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA \
  -f Dockerfile \
  .
```

Comment: Thank you answering the second method worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

update to the following, but can't help much further without full context of structure

COPY ./package.json ./

Comment: `./package.json` and `package.json` refer to the same "build context" relative path

Comment: Got the same error                                                                                                                                                                            
Step 3/8 : COPY ./package.json ./
COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat package.json: file does not exist
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1